# Power series of the modified Bessel function of the second kind

Tags: real-analysis, integration, special-functions, power-series, bessel-functions

I am looking for a power series representation of
$$ \frac{1}{K_{\nu}(x)}, $$
where $K_{\nu}$ denotes the modified Bessel function of the second kind and $\nu>-1/2$ is not an integer.
I know that such representations exist for the modified Bessel function of the first kind (e.g. here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0893965910000546) and I know that one can express the modified Bessel function of the second kind as a double sum (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.04283.pdf).